# How to execute this result within a limited function

Tags: javascript, counter

Questions are as follows：
The first time you call the add, it will return 1;
the second time you call, it returns 2;
Can only be written in function

```
var add = function () {
     // start only 
    
     // end 
};
 
console.log(add()); // 1
console.log(add()); // 2
```

The current idea is that a global variable is needed
So the current way of writing
But this way of writing does not meet the requirements

```
var add = (function () {
 let counter=0
   return function () {
  counter += 1; return counter;}
}();
```

I don't know how to adjust the code to solve this question thank you

Comment: What does "Can only be written in function" mean? No variables outside of it or no global variables? Can you use a closure? This isn't clear at all

Comment: Sorry,my explanation is not clear, there are no external variables and global variables

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the solutions that came to mind:

**Use a property assigned to the function**

```js
// in JS, a function is also an object; you can assign properties to it.
function add() {
  if (add.value === undefined) add.value = 0;
  return ++add.value;
}

console.log(add());
console.log(add());
```

**Create a local scope**

```js
var add = (function() {
  var value = 0;
  return function() {
    return ++value;
  };
})();

console.log(add());
console.log(add());
```

**Use the global scope**

```js
function add() {
  if (window._currentValue === undefined) window._currentValue = 0;
  return ++window._currentValue;
}

console.log(add());
console.log(add());
```

I think that the first solution may be of particular interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

somethig like this?

```js
var add = {
    time: 0,
    call: () => {
        add.time++;
        console.log(add.time);
    }
};

add.call(); // 1
add.call(); // 2
```

Comment: Works but doesn't meet the requirement. The requirement (probably homework) is `add()` twice.

Comment: It does not meet the homework requirements, but thank you very much for your answers

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this. It implicitely creates a global variable, which is dirty as hell, but it meets the (strange) requirements.

```js
var add = function () {
     if(typeof a === "undefined") a = 0;
     return ++a;
};
 
console.log(add()); // 1
console.log(add()); // 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a parameter inside `window` object. But I prefer the naxsi answer.

```js
var add = function () {
  if (window.added === undefined) window.added = 0;
  window.added += 1;
  return window.added;
};
 
console.log(add()); // 1
console.log(add()); // 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers :) Let me know the different writing

Comment: `window` **is** the global scope. They're the same thing